# oracle insert into very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have the following Oracle query, that executes quickly (in a few seconds):

```
select contract_id_fk as ct,
       max(trip_id) as tid,
       max(consumed_mileage) as cum
from trip
where to_date > to_date('20-12-2016','DD-MM-YYYY')
and contract_id_fk is not null
and vehicle_id_fk is not null
and trip_stop_status is null
group by contract_id_fk
```

the 'trip' table has a large number of row (more than 20 million)
Now, I want to insert the result of this query in a table, using:

```
INSERT INTO lst
select contract_id_fk as ct, 
       max(trip_id) as tid, 
       max(consumed_mileage) as cum 
from trip
where to_date > to_date('20-12-2016','DD-MM-YYYY') 
and contract_id_fk is not null 
and vehicle_id_fk is not null 
and trip_stop_status is null 
group by contract_id_fk
```

This is extremely slow. So slow that the transaction times out (more than 30 seconds in my case). Any idea why this is so slow, and how it could be optimized?

Comment: How are you running the `SELECT` query (SQLPlus, some tool, ...)? Please try `select count(*) from (yourSelect)` and see what happens.

Comment: Try adding append hint - /*+ append */  There can be many, many reasons (hardware, OS config, table config).  How many rows does select return?  How many indexes on table?

Comment: If you've 20M rows in the original table then you may have millions of result rows to write to table `lst`.  Output is inherently slower than input, plus you have to check constraints, update indices, *etc.*.  The relative timing you describe doesn't seem out of the ballpark.

Comment: in your case, would it be possible for you to do a `CTAS` first before inserting?

Comment: Difference is probably in I/O. Read means only read. Write means read original data and write of milions of result rows. You can also check autogrowth of log file and check free system resources when you are inserting data. Problem can be with indexes too - disable or drop indexes of destionation tables a recreate them after insert.

Comment: Can you provide a SQL Monitor report for the insert statement?

Comment: Some more infos : I run the select in Java through a jdbc connection. A select count(*) on trip returns about 22 million rows. However, because of the group by, sums and conditions, only a few thousand entries are written in the LST table at the end. Regarding the DB itself, I unfortunately don't have access to much information... I know we run Oracle on powerful machines (Oracle hexadata), but these machines are shared with other applications.

Comment: Trace the query and trace the insert.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to say what's the reason, as there could be multiple things, such as:

- insufficient memory, or redo log size
- suboptimal table settings (PCTFREE etc)
- hardware performance issue

Two things I'd recommend:

- check what are the wait events
- try insert with APPEND hint

```sql
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO lst
select contract_id_fk as ct,
max(trip_id) as tid, max(consumed_mileage) as cum
from trip where to_date > to_date('20-12-2016','DD-MM-YYYY')
and contract_id_fk is not null and vehicle_id_fk is not null and
trip_stop_status is null group by contract_id_fk
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the APPEND keyword. Any hints on how I can check the wait events?

Comment: Have a look at V$SESSION_EVENT.

Answer (score 1):

Try to select with the cursor, and insert in the loop. Like that;

```
DECLARE
       CURSOR SCURSOR IS
        select contract_id_fk as ct, 
           max(trip_id) as tid, 
           max(consumed_mileage) as cum 
        from trip
        where to_date > to_date('20-12-2016','DD-MM-YYYY') 
        and contract_id_fk is not null 
        and vehicle_id_fk is not null 
        and trip_stop_status is null 
        group by contract_id_fk ;
    BEGIN
       FOR RECS IN SCURSOR
       LOOP
            INSERT INTO lst 
            SELECT RECS.ct , RECS.tid , RECS.cum FROM DUAL;
            COMMIT;
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

check buffer cashe, i think the problem may be at buffer cashe
or try to gather table statistics

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! With "cashe" are you meaning `cache`?

Answer (score 0):

As they are still answers being made for this almost 4 years old question ...
The root cause for the slowness for a saturation in IO (RDS instance on AWS...) plus way too many group by/sort. More a database modeling problem than anything else.
Thank you for all those that tried to help!